# How to get my own GitHub events payload json for testing GitHub Actions locally?

Tags: github, github-actions

I use GitHub Actions and want to test it locally.
I'm using this tool and it works fine.
https://github.com/nektos/act

I can provide a event.json for local testing, but it's really hard to create a real event payload.

Is there any way to get real event payload?
For example, I create pull request on my repository from the console, and get that event payload json.

Comment: If anyone is wondering _how_ the `events.json` file can be provided, see https://github.com/nektos/act#events

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To get event data, you can use a GitHub action to print the event to the log.

```
# change this to the event type you want to get the data for
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, closed, reopened]

jobs:
  printJob:    
    name: Print event
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Dump GitHub context
      env:
        GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
      run: |
        echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```

Alternatively, you can find example event data in the documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#webhook-payload-example-30

Comment: Thank you very much.
I can print out a real event payload and using it for local testing. I submitted a edit request for woking correctly.

Comment: Note that this will give you the full webhook payload sent by github, however you only want to include the portion of the payload in the `event` key in your `event.json` file.

Comment: Word of warning with this: [the docs say](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) "Warning: When using the whole github context, be mindful that it includes sensitive information such as `github.token`. GitHub masks secrets when they are printed to the console, but you should be cautious when exporting or printing the context."