# Is there a way to see GitHub events?

Tags: github, github-actions

Working with github actions there are lots of events, and payloads, that can potentially trigger actions.

Is there a log or some way to see what events are being fired when I do various activities using git/github?

Comment: You can use github wenhook ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get my own github events payload json for testing github actions locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63803136/how-to-get-my-own-github-events-payload-json-for-testing-github-actions-locally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use github webhooks:

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/webhooks-and-events/about-webhooks

You can configure what event to  trigger the hook

the webhook reesponse will have property called action:

> action    string  Most webhook payloads contain an action property that
> contains the specific activity that triggered the event.

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads